# How to make custom field text stored in database a link in wordpress frontend

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a WordPress Form Plugin to store data. There's this text field which I'm using to store links such as http://example.com. I want to make the links clickable and where possible change it with HTML link markup

When I make a query inside the database like so, I see all the links listed which I want to alter

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_frm_item_metas` WHERE `meta_value` 
LIKE '%http://localhost/group1/add-temp/?frm_action=edit&entry=%' 
ORDER BY `wp_frm_item_metas`.`created_at` DESC
```

The links are already displaying in the frontend. Here is what the frontend links look like.

[image]

I'm learning to do this in localhost, WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a function around it like the following

```
public function wrap_links() {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}frm_item_metas WHERE meta_value LIKE '%http://localhost/group1/add-temp/?frm_action=edit&entry=%'";


    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );
    

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        echo '<a href="' . $result['name_of_link_column'] . '" target="_blank">' . $result['name_of_link_column'] . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Function with current user id query

```
 public function wrap_links() {
    global $wpdb;
    $userid = get_current_user_id();
    
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}frm_item_metas WHERE meta_value LIKE '%http://localhost/group1/add-temp/?frm_action=edit&entry=%' AND user_id = %d", $userid);


    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );
    

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        echo '<a href="' . $result['name_of_link_column'] . '" target="_blank">' . $result['name_of_link_column'] . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: The links are in the ```frm_item_metas table``` and ```meta_value``` column. I tried replacing ```name_of_link_column``` with ```meta_value``` but no data is fetched.

Comment: Try to print_r($results) to see the structure of the results first and put an example here

Comment: echo print_r($results); returns 1

Comment: you don't have to echo the print_r.I edited the query in the function as this wasn't escaped correctly, try it again (once again print_r the output)

Comment: No result is printed. I ran var_dump on results but it returned NULL

Comment: where do you call the function? Start the debug mode and log like explained here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
is there any log output when you try to query?

Comment: Your answer above worked. I was using it inside a widget and that's why it wasn't working properly. I have accepted your answer. Still one more quest, how can I limit the entry to the current logged in user? Any idea on how I can adapt the query?

Comment: I editet my initial post, as I dont know the structure of your table I can only guess the right query, but you can adapt it easily I guess